# error: org.hibernate.PropertyNotFoundException: no appropriate constructor in class: com.a.offering.dto.SellerDetailsDto

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, orm

I am using following query
String queryString = "select NEW com.h.offering.dto.SellerDetailsDto(p.productId,p.sellerId, p.sellerSku, p.sellPrice, " +
                "p.transferPrice, p.sellerMRP,p.aCommission,p.baseShippingFee,p.addnShippingFee, " +
                "p.propogationLevel,p.propogationValue,a.warehouseName,a.quantity,a.maxShippingTime,a.minShippingTime) "
                + "from PriceDetails p, AvailabilityDetails a "
                + "where a.productId = p.productId "
                + "and a.sellerSku = p.sellerSku "
                + "and  a.sellerId = :sellerId";

while executing i am getting error

org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException: Unable to locate appropriate constructor on class [com.a.offering.dto.SellerDetailsDto] [select NEW com.s.offering.dto.SellerDetailsDto(p.productId) from com.a.offering.db.domain.PriceDetails p, com.a.offering.db.domain.AvailabilityDetails a where a.productId = p.productId and a.sellerSku = p.sellerSku and  a.sellerId = :sellerId]
    at org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException.convert(QuerySyntaxException.java:54)
    at org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException.convert(QuerySyntaxException.java:47)
    at org.hibernate.hql.ast.ErrorCounter.throwQueryException(ErrorCounter.java:82)
    at org.hibernate.hql.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.analyze(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:261)
    at org.hibernate.hql.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:185)
    at org.hibernate.hql.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.compile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:136)

and so on...

I am unable to figure out the error. Help me out

```
The code for SellerDetailsDto.java is 

package com.a.offering.dto;
public class SellerDetailsDto {
    public String productId;
    public String sellerId;
    public String sellerSku;
    public Double sellPrice;
    public Double transferPrice;
    public Double sellerMRP;
    public Double a;
    public Double baseShippingFee;
    public Double addnShippingFee;
    public String propogationLevel;
    public String propogationValue;
    public String warehouseName;
    public int quantity;
    public int maxShippingTime;
    public int minShippingTime;

    public String getProductId() {
        return productId;
    }

    public void setProductId(String productId) {
        this.productId = productId;
    }

    public String getSellerId() {
        return sellerId;
    }

    public void setSellerId(String sellerId) {
        this.sellerId = sellerId;
    }

    public String getSellerSku() {
        return sellerSku;
    }

    public void setSellerSku(String sellerSku) {
        this.sellerSku = sellerSku;
    }

    public String getWarehouseName() {
        return warehouseName;
    }

    public void setWarehouseName(String warehouseName) {
        this.warehouseName = warehouseName;
    }

    public int getQuantity() {
        return quantity;
    }

    public void setQuantity(int quantity) {
        this.quantity = quantity;
    }

    public int getMaxShippingTime() {
        return maxShippingTime;
    }

    public void setMaxShippingTime(int maxShippingTime) {
        this.maxShippingTime = maxShippingTime;
    }

    public int getMinShippingTime() {
        return minShippingTime;
    }

    public void setMinShippingTime(int minShippingTime) {
        this.minShippingTime = minShippingTime;
    }

    public Double getSellPrice() {
        return sellPrice;
    }

    public void setSellPrice(Double sellPrice) {
        this.sellPrice = sellPrice;
    }

    public Double getTransferPrice() {
        return transferPrice;
    }

    public void setTransferPrice(Double transferPrice) {
        this.transferPrice = transferPrice;
    }

    public Double getSellerMRP() {
        return sellerMRP;
    }

    public void setSellerMRP(Double sellerMRP) {
        this.sellerMRP = sellerMRP;
    }

    public Double a() {
        return a;
    }

    public void a(Double aa) {
```

a       }

```
    public Double getBaseShippingFee() {
        return baseShippingFee;
    }

    public void setBaseShippingFee(Double baseShippingFee) {
        this.baseShippingFee = baseShippingFee;
    }

    public Double getAddnShippingFee() {
        return addnShippingFee;
    }

    public void setAddnShippingFee(Double addnShippingFee) {
        this.addnShippingFee = addnShippingFee;
    }

    public String getPropogationLevel() {
        return propogationLevel;
    }

    public void setPropogationLevel(String propogationLevel) {
        this.propogationLevel = propogationLevel;
    }

    public String getPropogationValue() {
        return propogationValue;
    }

    public void setPropogationValue(String propogationValue) {
        this.propogationValue = propogationValue;
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you post the code of com.tradus.offering.dto.SellerDetailsDto?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hibernate needs a constructor with at least package private (i. e. default) visibility.

Normally a parameterless constructor is necessary (which you implicitly have), but for your `select new ...` SellerDetailsDto needs a constructor with the 15 parameters which you give in the select statement. (Thought the error message demands a constructor with only the id as a parameter - it looks like if the error is coming from a different `select new` statement.) You don't have such a constructor.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you don't have a constructor in SellerDetailsDto that accepts the parameters that you are passing in the hql query. Add this constructor to your class:

```
public SellerDetailsDto(String productId, String sellerId,
            String sellerSku, Double sellPrice, Double transferPrice,
            Double sellerMRP, Double tradusCommission, Double baseShippingFee,
            Double addnShippingFee, String propogationLevel,
            String propogationValue, String warehouseName, int quantity,
            int maxShippingTime, int minShippingTime) {
        this.productId = productId;
        this.sellerId = sellerId;
        this.sellerSku = sellerSku;
        this.sellPrice = sellPrice;
        this.transferPrice = transferPrice;
        this.sellerMRP = sellerMRP;
        this.tradusCommission = tradusCommission;
        this.baseShippingFee = baseShippingFee;
        this.addnShippingFee = addnShippingFee;
        this.propogationLevel = propogationLevel;
        this.propogationValue = propogationValue;
        this.warehouseName = warehouseName;
        this.quantity = quantity;
        this.maxShippingTime = maxShippingTime;
        this.minShippingTime = minShippingTime;
    }
```

This could make some other code you have to stop working, because now there wont' be a default constructor available. To fix that, add a default constructor too:

```
public SellerDetailsDto() {}
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually this is problem on your root pom file. You want install lombok in your IDE & add dependency of lombok in root pom file I hope it will work

Comment: Hi D, if you are referring to one of the Lombok  constructor annotations then you should make that clear n your answer, this is for people unfamiliar with project  lombok and how it can help